# Excel VBA Macro to paste Picture as Bitmap to Word .dotm file

Tags: excel, bitmap, ms-word, paste, vba

I have a macro that copies a section in Excel, and pastes it into a Word template. The macro runs fine, except that the CopyPicture resolution is low, so I need to paste it as a Bitmap file to satisfy document quality requirements. The sample code is below:

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Documents.Open "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\XXXEngine\Debug\Quote Doc (Production).dotm"

With objWord.ActiveDocument

objWord.Visible = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TABLE OUTPUTS").Range("WORD_PREMIUM_SUMMARY").CopyPicture _
 Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
.Bookmarks("WORD_PREMIUM_SUMMARY").Range.Paste
```

What edits can be made to the CopyPicture _
 Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture section to allow for Bitmap pasting?

Comment: You might try `Format:=xlBitmap`

Comment: You should also look at Word's `PasteSpecial` - first in the UI, then apply what works best to your code. Office places information on the Clipboard in multiple formats; PasteSpecial allows you to choose which of those formats to use. These two suggestions in combination ought to be able to solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your suggestions... Will try them both to see if they resolve my resolution issues.